# How specific are LINQ .Contains IEnumerable results?

Tags: c#, linq

Assuming I have a Users table having several users with `Username` column values that follow:

```
Ortund
Richard
Happy McHappyFace
Flapjack
Harvey
Tabitha
Asha
```

If I query users with .Contains() on my LINQ query based on user input *"Happy"*:

```
var users = db.Users.Where(x => x.Username.Contains("Happy")).ToList();
```

Is the IEnumerable going to return every user record having *"Ha"* in the name (Richard, Happy McHappyFace, Harvey, Tabitha Asha), for example or will it return just the "Happy McHappyFace" user?

Comment: Why don't you just try it out? Spoiler: It won't :-)

Comment: Why would it return all users containing "Ha" if you've asked for "Happy"?

Comment: Only 1 results returned since the criteria uses "Happy". But if you using "Ha" as criteria there are 5 results.

Comment: @EpicKip please keep your input constructive. Whether its a stupid question or not, saying its a stupid question helps nobody, in fact, nothing about your comment is at all helpful in any way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks whether something specific and unreasonable will happen.

Answer (score 2):

Why would it return any match for `Ha`? You're specifically asking for users whose name contains `Happy` (in that capitalization, even), so you're only going to get one result here.

Comment: I wanted to understand how specific the results are. Whether it would use all of the exact string specified or if it would act more like a SQL LIKE query return even partial matches to the specified value. Also, not to be rude or anything, but I don't think asking a question within your answer is strictly speaking, the kind of thing that would count towards a high quality answer on the site here.

Comment: @Ortund `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username LIKE '%Happy%'` won't return `Harvey`

Comment: @Ortund Of course it is. You've asked a question after doing zero experimentation or investigation, using SO as a human-based REPL. You've made an incorrect assumption, it's perfectly valid to ask *why* you've made that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation from `String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> Returns a value indicating whether a specified substring occurs within this string.

So the entire match string (`Happy`) must match the whole or a part from the input string (`Happy McHappyFace`). It will only match on `Happy`, not on `H` or `Ha`.

It will translate to `where username like '%Happy%'`, which will match `Happy McHappyFace` only.

There is a slight catch though (but not in this case): LINQ has a `Contains` method (specifically [`Enumerable.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx)) that *could* match the signature (which would match on a character enumerable, which `string` happens to be). Since it is an extension method, the method belonging to the class will match first.

Comment: I think this is linq-to-sql, so this isn't really `String.Contains`. I've deleted a similar comment just now.

Comment: That `String.Contains` is translated in LINQ-to-SQL doesn't mean it will behave differently. In my opinion the analysis still holds, although it will have a different implementation when calling the database.

Comment: I don't understand what you say @JanesAbouChleih

Comment: LINQ-to-SQL translate that to SQL code. It will never actually call `string.Contains`.